# Failing to understand any-regular-compact constraints in Interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout, constraints

I have set my constraints in interface builder's **Main.storyboard** to compact(w) regular(h), however the view gets displayed in an inconsistent way (see image below).

[image]

Compact and regular says that it should fit all iPhone potrait modes. I don't understand why it does not fit my iPhone 5 simulator and why it appears differently.

As you can see from the image I also tried to put the view elements with a "placeholder" constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set constraints to your view. A very good tutorial you can find from :http://www.brianjcoleman.com/autolayout-xcode6/

Set the left & right constraint as you can see in the image.[image]

Comment: Thanks! It definetely helps however it does not explain how compact and regular have to do with this. Would you be able to articulate a bit more or provide some more references please?

Comment: What you need to do is uncheck fixed width if you have applied then set left & right constraint for each label you are using.